# Erlang function with number for parameter

Tags: erlang

Hi I'm learning Erlang via Learn You Some Erlang by Fred Hebert.

And I've come across a code that I'm confuse about:

```
sword(1) -> throw(slice);
sword(2) -> erlang:error(cut_arm);
sword(3) -> exit(cut_leg);
sword(4) -> throw(punch);
sword(5) -> exit(cross_bridge).

talk() -> "blah blah".

black_knight(Attack) when is_function(Attack, 0) ->
    try Attack() of
        _ -> "None shall pass."
    catch
        throw:slice -> "It is but a scratch.";
        error:cut_arm -> "I've had worse.";
        exit:cut_leg -> "Come on you pansy!";
        _:_ -> "Just a flesh wound."
    end.
```

So here's the confusion. I don't understand `sword(#)` function. Why are there number as parameter? The function `is_function` actually check if these function are of arity 0 and apparently all the `sword(#)` functions are of arity 0.

Also the way to pass in the `sword(#)` function to the `black_knight` function is different compare to the `talk` function.

Here's how the book pass a `sword` function and the `talk` function.

```
exceptions:black_knight(fun exceptions:talk/0).
```

vs

```
exceptions:black_knight(fun() -> exceptions:sword(1) end).
```

The `talk` function we just pass the function where as the `sword(1)` function we have to wrap it with a anonymous function. I don't get it.

So the questions are:

1. Why is passing these `sword(#)` different from `talk` function.
2. Why `sword(#)` have a number as a parameter?
3. Why `sword(#)` have 0 arity when it seems like it have an arity of 1 (I'm counting the number parameter as a parameter)?

[The chapter of the book I'm at.](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions#dealing-with-exceptions)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you look at the guard statement for the `black_knight` function, `is_function(Attack, 0)`, it will only match the definition if the function passed in takes 0 parameters.  Since talk takes 0 parameters, it can be passed in directly.  `sword` takes one parameter, so you need to wrap it in an anonymous function that takes 0 parameters before you can pass it in.
2. The number in the definition of each clause is an example of pattern matching.  If you call `sword` with `1` as the argument, you will execute the code in the clause `sword(1) ->`.  If you pass in `2` as the argument, you will execute the clause `sword(2) ->`.  See [this section](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) in Learn You Some Erlang for a more complete description.
3. `sword` does have an arity of 1, so you were counting parameters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `sword` function is to show off different kinds of errors that can be thrown. It accepts a parameter so it can have more than one clause. Fred probably chose integers because they are short, but that doesn't really matter.
The `sword` function really has an arity of one.

The `black_knight/1` function is supposed to show you how to catch the different error classes that exist in Erlang. It does this by calling the **zero-arity** function that is passed into it and providing a different response for different errors it might throw.

`sword/1` is passed into `black_knight/1` using an anonymous function
**because** `black_knight/1` only accepts functions of arity zero.
The anonymous function that is created by

```
fun () -> sword(1) end
```

is a function of arity zero that calls `sword/1` with one argument.

`talk/0` can be passed directly because it already is a zero arity function.